# Cross domain cookies in iOS 7

Tags: javascript, ios, iframe, cookies, ios7

I'm trying to use the XAuth cross domain cookie trick with iOS 7. It does not seem to work.

When I mention cookies below it's really both cookies and localStorage values being set.

I have a page on www.client1.com opening a static webpage in an iframe on www.server.com that sets a cookie with a unique id. Next I open a new window/tab that loads www.client2.com that opens an iframe to www.server.com and attempt to access that same unique id from the cookie previously set.

This works on all platforms, including previous versions of iOS, that I have tried. But not on iOS 7.

I'm using the postMessage method to send information between the iframe and main frame.

What have they changed in iOS 7? Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar problem with a child iframe on b.com with an app cache manifest, hosted in a page served from a.com. The cache manifest would never be fetched by Safari so the child app would never be cached. Happened in WebViews also.

It turns out that iOS7 has a new Privacy/Security setting for *blocking* cookies (in previous versions of iOS the setting was for *accepting* cookies), and I found it must be set to 'Never'. The default is to block cookies 'From third parties and advertisers', and that is why my cache manifest was being blocked, and why your cookies aren't being retained.

I have a specialized audience so I can direct users to change their settings. I suppose without this luxury you would have to resort to redirection-fu to flip between the domains and back to ensure that the proper cookies get dropped. However, that approach still may not let child iframes see their own cookies -- Safari may block (i.e., not send) those cookies when the iframe is hosted in a page from a different domain. I haven't tested to confirm this, however.

Comment: Noticed the same behavior. 
My application needs to work with default settings though.
Evercookies hack-ish methods of PNG-storage, etag and one more thing I don't remember works. It's not polished and it relies on glitches. Mine needs to be stable.

Answer (score 0):

FYI...
I am a Product Manager who's app had an issue with the cookie updates made in iOS7.0
- We use cookies to support user authentication....and the new cookie policy applied to both Safari AND apps.

This issue appears to have been addressed in iOS 7.0.3

Comment: Seriousley! That is awesome news if that is the case.

Comment: From what I find nothing has changed in iOS 7.0.3.
I still can't get the values in an iFrame from a cookie from one domain when set in an iFrame on another domain.

Comment: I'm seeing the same as @GusOst - still broken, even in 7.0.4. Perhaps there's a minor difference between how apps and Safari are handling third party cookies?